# Multiple uploads using FuelPHP

Tags: file, upload, save, fuelphp

I am trying to uplods multiple file using Upload class of Fuel PHP int the form I have 3 input fields for the files. All the files are image with .png extension.

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file1">
<input type="file" name="file" id="file2">
<input type="file" name="file" id="file3">
```

But in my controller the $uploaded_files counts returns only 1. It only returns the last input file. How is this so? Am I missing something? Thanks!

```
My Controller

$config = array(
'path' => DOCROOT,
'ext_whitelist' => array('img', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png'),
'randomize' => true,
);

Upload::process($config);

if (Upload::is_valid()){

Upload::save();

$uploaded_files = Upload::get_files();

}
```

Comment: Can you expand on your example form please? If your inputs all have the same name then only one of those will actually end up being processed anyway.

Comment: Here's my actual form :<form action="upload_file.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file" id="file1">
<input type="file" name="file" id="file2">
<input type="file" name="file" id="file3">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

Answer (score 1):

As I stated in my comment to your question you have named your inputs all the same. If you wish to have an array of files you can use `name[]` instead of `name`. This means they will be submitted as an array rather than a single value that gets overwritten by fields with the same name.